# How to use window functions to get meterics for today, last 7 days, last 30 days for each value of the date?

Tags: sql, etl, amazon-redshift, window-functions

My problem seems simple on paper:

For a given date, give me active users for that given date, active users in given_Date()-7, active users in a given_Date()-30

i.e. sample data.

```
"timestamp" "user_public_id"
"23-Sep-15" "805a47023fa611e58ebb22000b680490"
"28-Sep-15" "d842b5bc5b1711e5a84322000b680490"
"01-Oct-15" "ac6b5f70b95911e0ac5312313d06dad5"
"21-Oct-15" "8c3e91e2749f11e296bb12313d086540"
"29-Nov-15" "b144298810ee11e4a3091231390eb251"
```

for 01-10 the count for today would be 1, last_7_days would be 3, last_30_days would be 3+n (where n would be the count of the user_ids that fall in dates that precede Oct 1st in a 30 day window)

I am on redshift amazon. Can somebody provide a sample sql to help me get started?
the outputshould look like this:

```
"timestamp" "users_today", "users_last_7_days", "users_30_days"
"01-Oct-15"           1                 3           (3+n)
```

Comment: I don't think you need windowing functions for this, it's pretty simple.

Comment: I think you should take a look at what site you are on, and not post comments that don't contribute anything.

Comment: Sorry, i cannot reliably enter much more than that from my smartphone.  I will try to add an answer from my laptop as soon as I can ...

Answer (score 2):

I know asking for help/incomplete solutions are frowned upon, but this is not getting any other attention so I thought I would do my bit.

I have been pulling my hair out trying to nut this one out, alas, I am a beginner and something is not clicking for me. Perhaps yourself or others will be able to drastically improve my answer, but I think I am on the right track.

```
SELECT replace(convert(varchar, [timestamp], 111), '/','-') AS [timestamp], -- to get date in same format as you require
(SELECT COUNT([TIMESTAMP]) FROM #SIMPLE WHERE ([TIMESTAMP]) = ([timestamp])) AS users_today,
(SELECT COUNT([TIMESTAMP]) FROM #SIMPLE WHERE [TIMESTAMP] BETWEEN DATEADD(DY,-7,[TIMESTAMP]) AND [TIMESTAMP]) AS users_last_7_days ,
(SELECT COUNT([TIMESTAMP]) FROM #SIMPLE WHERE [TIMESTAMP] BETWEEN DATEADD(DY,-30,[TIMESTAMP]) AND [timestamp]) AS users_last_30_days
FROM #SIMPLE
GROUP BY [timestamp]
```

Starting with this:

```
CREATE TABLE #SIMPLE (
[timestamp] datetime, user_public_id varchar(32)
)

INSERT INTO #SIMPLE 
VALUES('23-Sep-15','805a47023fa611e58ebb22000b680490'),
('28-Sep-15','d842b5bc5b1711e5a84322000b680490'),
('01-Oct-15','ac6b5f70b95911e0ac5312313d06dad5'),
('21-Oct-15','8c3e91e2749f11e296bb12313d086540'),
('29-Nov-15','b144298810ee11e4a3091231390eb251')
```

The problem I am having is that each row contains the same counts, despite my grouping by [timestamp].

Comment: Thanks for trying, but I don't recognize that flavor of SQL. I have posted the solution below.

Comment: @smooth_smoothie this is pretty standard SQL, except for the `#` to indicate a temporary table, which is a SQL Server idiom.  If you need a particular flavor of SQL, you should indicate that in your question or in the tags.  Also the `DATEADD`, but date arithmetic is one of those things that's very non-standard across implementations.

Comment: Hmm, I just checked and the `DATEADD` appears to be valid SQL for Redshift.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1-- Create a table which has daily counts.

```
create temp table daily_mobile_Sessions as
select "timestamp" ,
count(user_public_id) over (partition by  "timestamp"  ) as "today"
from mobile_sessions 
group by 1, mobile_sessions.user_public_id
order by 1 DESC
```

Step 2 -- From the table above. We create yet another table which can use the "today" field, and we apply the window function to Sum the counts.

```
select "timestamp", today,
sum(today) over (order by "timestamp" rows between 6 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW) as "last_7days",
sum(today) over (order by "timestamp" rows between 29 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW) as "last_30days"
 from daily_mobile_Sessions group by "timestamp"  , 2 order by 1 desc
```

Comment: Step 2 only works if there's exactly one row per day.  Any more or less, any deviation at all and it doesn't work (for instance, your sample data does not conform to this).  As long as you know for sure that that is true, then no problem, but if not then you'll need a different approach.